# Convert Html Nav to Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, navigation, nav, navbar

im trying to convert this navigation menu

```
    <ul class="main-navigation">
        <li class="current"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">exhibitions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">artists</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>

    </ul>
```

into a wordpress navigation menu, i believe its just a little bit of code to do it. But not sure

Hope someone can help

Denver

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make your own theme or are you just trying to edit the nav bar in a wordpress install?  If you are attempting to make a theme check out [this info](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus).  If you are trying to edit the nav bar on an install you should be able to do from within the admin panel with changing any of the code I believe.

Edit: Here is the info for doing it through the [admin panel](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_Screen)

Comment: so i would have to register the nav?

Comment: To do it through the admin panel?

Comment: im just looking for the simplest way to do this, as the nav bar is only for the pages.

Comment: try the link i added above to do it through the admin panel

Comment: well i dont really need anything in the admin panel i was thinking something simple like this:                                  <?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu' => 'mainnav', 'menu_class' => 'nav-bar-content', 'menu_id' => 'navigation', 'container' => false, 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'show_home' => '1')); ?>

so i'm wondering how i'd style it to be like the static one?

Answer (score 0):

I would add links instead through the WP Admin Panel, then style them separately in your own theme. That way your nav should stay active even after a major WP update that could potentially break the custom code you're trying to use for your custom menu.

Comment: im not sure i understand that?

Comment: What he is saying is that if you edit the php source of the wordpress install a future version of wordpress could break the code that you added yourself as the new version would not be expecting you changes to be there

Comment: Why can't you do this through the admin panel? It's the most straightforward way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In child's theme functions.php file add this below:

```
function register_header_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_header_menu' );
```

Then paste this part below where you want the navigation to be in the template I'm guess the header.php

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu' ) ); ?>
```

Add links inside WordPress and style with CSS.